# I can't var_dump my module's info

Tags: joomla-2.5, development, module

Sorry for asking another question, but I really need an answer on this.

My module is called mod_improvedmenu. I've been experimenting a bit (I'm still learning, I need some help on this subject because it's a returning issue), and the thing is, when I do a var_dump on the $module variable, it returns an array with all the information I need.

However, when I set that $module to be mod_improvedmenu

```
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_improvedmenu');
var_dump($module);
```

It returns an empty array. It should work, but it doesn't. I also checked the database if there happens to be 2 modules with the same name, but there's not.

Do you have any idea what could be going on here?
When I do the same thing with simply mod_menu, it works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure it meets the following criteria:

1. It is enabled
2. It is assigned to the current menu item or is assigned to all menu items
3. The user meets the access level requirements.

**Note:** When using your code in an external PHP file, the module must be assigned to all pages

Comment: All of those are correct. I meet every criteria.

Comment: ok, and have you ensured you're running the latest version of the Joomla 2.5 series? (2.5.27). If not then please update as it could be a bug

Comment: I'm on .27 now, still got the same issue.

Comment: Am I right in assuming you're still trying to do this in an external PHP file?

Comment: Yes. But, for tests sake I'm using a new module new, and in the default file I did a var_dump on the $module variable, which worked fine,  but as soon as I set it to 'mod_mymodule' it returns an empty array eventhough I am using the right module name.

Comment: I have just made a test. It appears you need to assign the module to all pages. If you assign it to selected pages, it won't work.

Comment: I fixed it--and it works on selected pages too :) Thanks Lodder, for your time today and yesterday.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted in the end :)

Comment: You were right about having to assign it to all pages by the way. Good that you added that as a note.